# AEM 6.1 extend ThumbnailProcess Workflow Step

Tags: java, maven, aem

I'm trying to extend the ***com.day.cq.dam.core.process.ThumbnailProcess*** class.

I'm using Java JDK 1.8.0_65, Maven 3.0.5 and Adobe AEM 6.1

When I compile my code I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr (generate-scr-descriptor)
>   on project my.pack.common.PROCESS: Execution
>   generate-scr-descriptor of goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr failed: An API
>   incompatibility was encountered while executing
>   org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr: java.lang.VerifyError:
>   (class: com/day/cq/dam/core/process/ThumbnailProcess, method: 
>   signature: ()V) Constructor must call super()or this()
>
> [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0 [ERROR] strategy =
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
>
> [ERROR]
>   urls[0] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/maven-scr-plugin/1.20.0/maven-scr-plugin-1.20.0.jar
>
> [ERROR] urls[1] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.2/maven-archiver-2.2.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[2] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[3] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[4] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr.generator/1.12.0/org.apache.felix.scr.generator-1.12.0.jar
>
> [ERROR] urls[5] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.2/asm-all-5.0.2.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[6] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.core/4.2.0/org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
>
> [ERROR] urls[7] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.compendium/4.2.0/org.osgi.compendium-4.2.0.jar
>
> [ERROR] urls[8] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
>
> [ERROR] urls[9] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Dwecol/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar
>   [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1 [ERROR] import: Entry[import 
>   from realm
>   ClassRealm[project>mypro:my.pack.edidomus.common.PROCESS:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]] 
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. 
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. 
>   [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

My class is somenthing like this:

```
@Component
@Service
@Properties({
@Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION, value ="MyThumbnailProcess"),
@Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR, value = "Me"),
@Property(name = "process.label", value = "My Thumbnail Proc2")}
public class MyThumbnailProc extends ThumbnailProcess {
public MyThumbnailProc(){super();}
@Override
public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaData) throws WorkflowException {
//do stuff -> create newMetaDataMap 
super.execute(workItem, workflowSession, newMetaDataMap);
}
```

Do you have any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a test you could try the aem6 api dependency and not the 6.1 uber jar.  My guess is that you are extending an obfuscated class. If you are able to get past this with the 6.0 dependency, then you could ask Adobe for the unobfiscated 6.1 jar

```
<depen­dency>
         <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
        <arti­fac­tId>aem-api</arti­fac­tId>
        <ver­sion>6.0.0.1</ver­sion>
         <scope>pro­vided</scope> 
</depen­dency>
```

Comment: Seems like ThumbnailProcess  has been introducted with AEM 6.1 -- [Here the 6.0 package doc](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/core/process/package-frame.html)

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to uber.jar and you might need unobfuscated version of the jar. You should raise a ticket with daycare, if you are not able to resolve this.